# Qt C++ Conversion from QJsonValue to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

I have a large (megabytes) string in a `QJsonValue`, that I need to convert to `QByteArray`, as I am sending the string as data with a `QNetworkRequest`.

Currently I am doing this:

```
myQJsonObject["myQJsonValue"].toString().toUtf8()
```

Would this incur copying the same data to memory many times for some reason? If so, how would you go about implementing this without unnecessary copyings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `myQJsonObject["myQJsonValue"].toString()` does not involve data copy thanks to copy-on-write semantics of Qt.

The `toUtf8` call is costly. `QString` stores the data as Unicode (16-bit `QChar`s), and encoding it in UTF-8 involves more than data copy.

`QString::constData()` returns a pointer to the underlying character array. But then, each character is represented by 2 bytes instead of 1 or 2 bytes in case of Utf-8. This might mean sending two times more data over the network.

So if your data consists of mostly ASCII characters, then UTF-8 is probably a better option. If it contains lots of non-Ascii characters, and the other side can handle UTF-16, then UTF-16 is worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

and why you do not use `QJsonDocument`? This should be used for reading and writing. There is a method [QJsonDocument::toBinaryData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toBinaryData).
This API should do everything with most effective way.

---

### Update to comment:

Single JSon value is must be one of other JSon types: object, string or some number. I'm pretty sure you have JSon object.
So your code should look like this::

```
JSonValue val = someJsond["someKey"];
if (val.isObject()) {
    QJSonDocument doc(val.toObject());
    SendToServer(doc.toBinaryData());
} else {
    // error or:
    SendToServer(val.toString().toUtf8());
}
```

Comment: Well this is a very interesting suggestion, thank you very much.

Comment: Would it incur any extra cost to use the QJsonDocument constructor, giving it a large QJsonObject as parameter?

Comment: The question is what are you sending to server? I doubt this is a single `QJsonValue`. It must be an `QJsonArray` or `QJsonObject`. I never seen a server which sends or accepts single JSon value. That is why `QJsonDocument` doens't have a constructor for `QJsonValue`.

Comment: It is a large chunk of json, that I save (or update) at the user's Dropbox account, as a .json file.

Comment: Meaning of course that the nested QJsonValue in question here contains a large json object. I think toBinaryData() should be ok, as, although I save the file as .json, there is no need for the server to interpret the data as json, so the content type can be application/octet-stream.